# Scala Update first element of collection

Tags: performance, scala, collections, stack

I need a collection that is efficient when pre-appending and returning the first element. A stack does the job well.

Now, the objects of the stacks is also a collection. Let's say it is a list. So I have a Stack of Lists.

My question is the following:
If I want to append an element to the list of the head of the Stack, is my only choice to: pop the head, add the element to the list and push the new list? 
Efficiently wise, all times are constant, correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with immutable collections the list you'd add and the outer stack(or List) would be new as well so it doesn't matter. Still lists are efficient in prepend and head operations (you can check doc for [Collection - performance characteristics](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html) for details on the costs of operations)